# How do I use Socat to log multiple clients with a single socket per client?

Tags: bash, logging, parallel-processing, socat

I have multiple clients that needs to send realtime a log (/tmp/action.log) that is filled by a logmessage() bash function (I'm in an initrd). logmessage can be modified to do a Socat to a local socket if needed.
On the server side, when a new client opens a connection, it sends its MAC address, then it sends lines from time to time.
What I want to avoid is a new process each time a message is sent to a client.
I need the connection between server and client to stay alive until the client Socat is killed or the server forked script exists.
I need that multiple client can send their logs concurrently

As I understand, on the server, this can be done with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Function run per single client.
function process_log() {
    read MAC
    while read MSG
    do
        case "$MSG" in
            reset)
                /bin/rm -f /tmp/test_$MAC.log
                ;;
            endlog)
                exit 0;
                ;;
            *)
                echo "$MSG" >> /tmp/test_$MAC.log
                ;;
        esac
    done
}

export -f process_log

socat -vv TCP-LISTEN:8182,crlf,reuseaddr,fork SYSTEM:"/bin/bash -c 'process_log'"
```

My problem is that the connection is cleared each time I send a message, thus the server Socat spawn a new bash for each line which is ugly and eat lots of PID.

I tried the following stuff to have a stable persistent socket between the client and the server:

On the client, I initialise a local Socat server (once):

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/logger.socket,ignoreeof TCP-CONNECT:$SERVER_IP:8182&
echo $! > /tmp/socat.pid
test -S /tmp/logger.socket && socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/logger.socket <<EOF
$CLIENT_MAC
reset
EOF
```

and my logmessage() does (multiple times) (aside filling /tmp/action.log and other console things):

```
test -S /tmp/logger.socket && socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/logger.socket <<EOF
$MAC
$*
EOF
```

In my logmessage() above, I have to resend the MAC address each time as the connection is closed at each call. (It shouldn't be necessary provided a  connection stay alive between client and server until I send endlog keyword)

So 2 solutions:

- Either I tail -f the log file to the server after having sent the MAC address (but I have to process lines on the server side to convert to xml (thus eating PIDs)
- Or I can have the semdmessage() function sending the data (converted to xml) to something that stays open.

Unfortunately, I'm no skilled enough to understand how to use Socat in an efficient way and was unable to find (identify) a solution to a similar problem on the web).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can solve problem with [daggy](https://daggy.dev):

1. Write Data Aggregation Config `config.yaml`l like this:

```
aliases:
 - &actionLog
   name: actionLog
   command: tail -f /tmp/action.log
   extension: log
 - &auth_ssh
   login: user
   password: password

sources:
   host1:
     type: ssh
     connection:
       *auth_ssh
     host: 192.168.1.10
     commands:
       - *actionLog
    hostN:
     type: ssh
     connection:
       *auth_ssh
     host: 192.168.1.N
     commands:
       - *actionLog
```

2. Run daggy with next this config:

```sh
daggy -o log_streams config.yaml
```

3. In folder `log_streams` you will get all logs at runtime